# Mysql query for updating entry doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

```
$parameter = $_GET["o"];                                                            

$result = decode($password, $parameter, $salt);                      


if (strtolower($result['statusmessage']) == 'ok') {                                     
    $uservar = $result['id'];                                            

    print PHP_EOL . $uservar . PHP_EOL; 
    print PHP_EOL . $vipstatus . PHP_EOL; 
    print PHP_EOL . $callstatus . PHP_EOL; 

    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "UPDATE user SET vipstatus='1', SET callstatus='1' WHERE username ='$uservar'";

    print PHP_EOL . $sql . PHP_EOL; 

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close(); 
    }
?>
```

It works so far, the vipstatus for the user is set as `1`, but the callstatus is set as `0` and I want it to be `1` as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Query needs `SET` only once. `SET vipstatus='1', callstatus='1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is in the query, use **SET** keyword once:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE user SET vipstatus='1', callstatus='1' WHERE username ='$uservar'";
```

Comment: Keep cool it tells me to wait 11 minutes before i can accept 

Answer (score 2):

No need for two times `SET` in query, Do like below:-

```
 $sql = "UPDATE user SET vipstatus='1',callstatus='1' WHERE username ='$uservar'";
```

Note:- `SET` need to use only once in update query.

Answer (score 0):

Change this to

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET vipstatus='1', SET callstatus='1' WHERE username ='$uservar'";
```

this

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET vipstatus='1',  callstatus='1' WHERE username ='$uservar'";
```

**Note** :

`UPDATE user SET vipstatus='1',  callstatus='1', WHERE username` this line is not works. Due to `s='1', WHERE` you can see (`,`) comma is on there.